# Can I use Bessel functions of any order in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Does anyone know of using Bessel functions of any order in Haskell?

If such a library does not exist is there a C library of freely accessible mathematical functions containing such Bessel functions, preferably being able to work with big-floats?

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted. I don't think there is anything on Hackage but it wouldn't be hard to write your own. EDIT: I am guessing it got down voted because it didn't show any research effort. Perhaps you should have said you had googled / looked at Hackage?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [cmath package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmath-0.3/docs/Foreign-C-Math-Double.html) that allows you to interface with standard C math functions, I think it has the Bessel functions, specifically `j0`, `j1` and `y0`, `y1`, `yn`.